# Can we use scrollTo() function instead of animate function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

can we use  scrollTo() function instead of animate function ?

I use animate function I want to do same functionality without using animate function.can we use scrollTo function?

```
$("#new_div").on("click", ".ui-keyboard-has-focus .keyboard_arrow_container li", function (event) {
//.scroll_bottom_arrow
switch ($(this).index()) {
case 0:
    {

        $(".wrapper_div_id").animate({
            scrollLeft: "-=" + 500 + "px"
        });
        break;
    }
case 1:
    {
        $(".wrapper_div_id").animate({
            scrollLeft: "+=" + 500 + "px"
        });
        break;
    }
case 2:
    {
        $(".wrapper_div_id").animate({
            scrollTop: "-=" + 300 + "px"
        });
        break;
    }
case 3:
    {
        $(".wrapper_div_id").animate({
            scrollTop: "+=" + 300 + "px"
        });
        break;
    }

}

// event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Well what happened when you tried it?

Comment: If you just want to scroll instantly I would think the smallest possible change to your code would be to just specify an `.animate()` time of 0ms. jQuery doesn't have a `.scrollTo()` method built-in, although there are plugins for it. The standard JS `window.scrollTo()` method isn't a suitable replacement for the code you've shown.

Comment: can you please give fiddle..

Comment: How about _you_ give a starting fiddle? You said your current code works, so put that in a fiddle with some suitable html, and then explain more clearly what you want to do - the `window.scrollTo()` method scrolls the whole document, but your code moves a specific element within the document, so they're not really comparable.

Answer (score 0):

scrollTo() is not animated, there is a plug-in called jquery.scrollTo that does the same job as scrollTo() but with animation.